# Get response from another route in Laravel 4 (Dynamic Routing)

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my problem.
My URLs are like these :

http://mysite.com/foo

http://mysite.com/bar

http://mysite.com/foo is a user page and will be handled by UserController.

http://mysite.com/bar is a group page and will be handled by GroupController.

I have also a Config file that contains information for these routes.

```
return Array(
    'foo' => '/user/1',
    'bar' => '/group/1'
)
```

How i should implements this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set up routing path in your routes.php  , like in docs

http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing

Comment: I know about Routing! but this question is about Dynamic Routing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('user/{id}','UserController@show');
Route::get('group/{id}','GroupController@show');
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug){
            $MenuList = Config::get('menulist');
            $request = Request::create($MenuList[$slug], 'GET');
            return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
        }
});


//menulist.php
return Array(
    'foo' => '/user/1',
    'bar' => '/group/1'
)
```